# как поместить разные условия исполнения OnClick в radibuttons

Tags: java, android

Есть дисплей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И **код**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{
    ImageView plus;
    ImageView minus;
    TextView tvResult;
    TextView cena;
    TextView cena_53_skritaya;
    TextView cena_73_skritaya;
    RadioGroup radioGroup_cena;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        plus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.plus);
        plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        minus= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.minus);
        minus.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
        cena = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cena);
        cena_53_skritaya = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_53);
        cena_73_skritaya = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_73);
        radioGroup_cena = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup_cena);
        radioGroup_cena.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.radioButton_250:
                        cena.setText("53");
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioButton_500:
                        cena.setText("73");
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        int parse_kolichestvo;
        int parse_cena_53;
        int num2 = 1;
        int result = 0;
        int resultcena=0;

        // читаем TextView и заполняем переменные числами
        parse_kolichestvo = Integer.parseInt(tvResult.getText().toString());
        parse_cena_53 = Integer.parseInt(cena_53_skritaya.getText().toString());
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.plus:
                result = parse_kolichestvo + num2;
                resultcena= result*parse_cena_53;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.minus:
                result = parse_kolichestvo - num2;
                if (parse_kolichestvo==1){
                    return;
                }
                resultcena= result*parse_cena_53;
        }
        // формируем строку вывода
        tvResult.setText( String.valueOf(result) );
        cena.setText( String.valueOf(resultcena) );

    }
}
```

Как Вы видите в OnClick программа парсит первое число (53) и умножает на количество, в данном случае 1, плюсом и минусом(Image View) изменяется количество, и задается шаг. Теперь вопрос как перенести этот цикл в

```
 switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radioButton_250:
                    cena.setText("53");
                    break;
```

И соответственно задать другой цикл для работы с

```
 case R.id.radioButton_500:
                    cena.setText("73");
                    break;
```

Но с парсингом уже 73, а не 53.
Я пытался сам, но возникают проблемы с обозначением ImageView для каждого из циклов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Намудрено как то... не увидел в прикрепленном коде ни одного цикла который вы хотите перенести... Но глядя на вашу свитч кейс конструкцию в `onClick` методе я понял что вы не особо то ведаете что творите:). Однако все мы были когда то такими - так что я все же попытаюсь.

Вообщем из того что я попытался разгадаться из вашего ребуса(не уверен что правильно разгадал) - вам нужно в `onClick` методе использовать данные из поля, которые заполняются по средствам выбора ячейки в `CheckGroup`, а не из `Integer.parseInt(cena_53_skritaya.getText().toString())`. Тогда вам будет не важно какой элемент выбран и логика верно отработает именно для той цены которую вы засетили в `CheckGroup`.

Comment: Спасибо), Все верно, ребус Вы решили)))

Comment: @ Eugene Troyanskiyy Не хочу открывать новую тему, но Вы не подскажете как правильно обратиться к переменной в onClick из OnCheckChanged. Обноовил тело письма скрином среды разработки, чтобы вы поняли, о чем я.)

Comment: @Romikromikromik Если у вас другая проблема - создавайте новый вопрос, здесь Q&A, а не форум с обсуждениями. Принцип такой - **один** конкретный вопрос - верный ответ, без всяких  - "а вот еще у меня .." или тому подобного.

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: @Romikromikromik создайте глобальную переменную и в каждом кейсе onCheckChange присваивайте ей значение. А в onClick просто используйте эту глобальную переменную в которой будет лежать именно та цена которая установленна в данный момент.